# Horizontal sliding using jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slide

I need to make a div dissapear to the left and make a second one appear from the right. I am using th following jquery UI functions to do this:

```
hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

The issue I got is that the first and second div are not alligned when disappearing and entering as you can see in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/oagxfpru/

I would like to make the second div be at the same height when entering the scene.

Any idea?
Thanks for the help <3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#second").hide();
    
    $("#toSecond").on('click', function() {
        $("#first").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
        $("#second").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    });

    $("#toFirst").on('click', function() {
        $("#second").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
        $("#first").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    })
});
```

```css
#first{float:left;
width:100%;}
#second{width:100%;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id='first'>
        Some content here<br/>
        that should slide to the left<br/>
        No problem with that
        <input type="button" id="toSecond" value="to second">
    </div>
    <div id='second'>
        This should be at the same height<br/>
        then the first div when sliding to the left<br/>
        This ain't working properly :/
        <input type="button" id="toFirst" value="to first">
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help ! :)

Comment: And what should I do in the case I got a third div? what CSS should I add? Thanks again for the help :)